# Angular: "ng build -prod" produces error for jsnlog

Tags: angular, jsnlog

I get the following error if I try to execute `ng build --prod`:

```
ERROR in ./src/$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'jsnlog/Definitions/jl' in 'C:\xxx\src\$$_gendir\app'
 @ ./src/$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory.ts 31:0-45
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi ./src/main.ts
```

This error happens only  when i run `ng build --prod` and works fine when i run `ng build` without any parameters,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced this same issue. The problem is that this library is NOT angular AOT compilation ready because it is missing `metadata.json` file. That is why production build fails and dev build works.

Instead of registering it to angular service injector, you can directly import it into your error handler service and use it. It makes testing little harder though.

In your service which extends angular ErrorHandler:

```
import { JL } from 'jsnlog';
```

and in `handleError` method, do:

```
JL().fatalException('Exception', error);
```

Comment: Thank you for your hint. I solved my problem by adding jsnlog as static library (not via npm). But your approach is better.